# How to compare values across pair of fields in Redshift database table considering NULL?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table as below.

[image]

it is created with pair of fields such as Old and New, here i would like to give a tag to each observation as CHANGE and NO_CHANGE considering the below rules.

NO_CHANGE:

1. if all of pair values are EQUAL it is tagged as NO_CHANGE ignoring NULL pairs

CHANGE:

1. if any of pair value is not equal ignoring NULL pairs it is tagged as CHANGE like the **YELLOW COLORED LINE IN TABLE.**

Answer (score 1):

Just as you describe it.  If they are equal or either is NULL then they are a match.  Perform AND logic across all 3 pairs.

```
SELECT DECODE ( (A1_old = A1_new OR A1_old is NULL OR A1_new is NULL)
  AND (B1_old = B1_new OR B1_old is NULL OR B1_new is NULL)
  AND (C1_old = C1_new OR C1_old is NULL OR C1_new is NULL),
  true, 'NO_CHANGE', 'CHANGE') AS Comment
FROM <table>;
```

You didn't mention what to do if one value of a pair is NULL and not the other.  The above generates "NO_CHANGE" if one of the values is NULL.  Below is if you want this to be "CHANGE".

```
SELECT DECODE ( (A1_old = A1_new OR (A1_old is NULL AND A1_new is NULL))
  AND (B1_old = B1_new OR (B1_old is NULL AND B1_new is NULL))
  AND (C1_old = C1_new OR (C1_old is NULL AND C1_new is NULL)),
  true, 'NO_CHANGE', 'CHANGE') AS Comment
FROM <table>;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
case when A1_old <> A1_new
       or B1_old <> B1_new
       or C1_old <> C1_new
     then 'CHANGE' else 'NO_CHANGE'
end as Comment
```